# passing values from a receiver to a button

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I have a broadcast receiver for "IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)", and it is registered in onStart and unregistered in onStop. and i also in my 
layout i have a a button to turn the BT ON/OFF and another button "btnDiscover" that when pressed should display information about the state of the discovered devices which are contained in the object "stateExtDevice" 
as shown belwo in the code of the Broadcast reciever:

**BroadCast Receiver**:

```
switch (action) {
        case BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND:
            Log.d(TAG, LogAnd.show("onReceive", "BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND"));

            int stateExtBond = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_BOND_STATE, BluetoothDevice.ERROR);
            switch(stateExtBond) {
                case BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING:
                    Log.d(TAG, LogAnd.show("onReceive", "BOND_BONDING"));
                    break;
                case BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED:
                    Log.d(TAG, LogAnd.show("onReceive", "BOND_BONDED"));
                    break;
                case BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE:
                    Log.d(TAG, LogAnd.show("onReceive", "BOND_NONE"));
                    break;
            }
            BluetoothDevice stateExtDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            //setBTDeviceExtrs(stateExtDevice);
            adapter.add(stateExtDevice.getName()+"\n"+stateExtDevice.getAddress()+"\n"+stateExtDevice.getBondState()
                    +"\n"+stateExtDevice.getType()+"\n"+stateExtDevice.getUuids());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            break;
```

the problem is when i am onPause state to activate the BT manually, the broadcast receiver goes into "case BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND" and display the information
immediately without the button being pressed, and I want only these information to be displayed only when the button "btnDiscover" is pressed. i thought of solving this issue by using setters and getters methods, but my question is could this problem be solved by interface for an example? and is there any better solutions

Comment: I didn't get you issue exactly. Do you want to stop bluetooth discovery when app is in pause state or you don't want to display the discovered device until btnDiscover is pressed?

Comment: @EEJ the latter one.."  to display the discovered device until btnDiscover is pressed"

Comment: then you should not call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged from inside switch. Call it only when btnDiscover is pressed. That way newly discovered devices will be add on your adapter but it will not update the list.